# How to use Tess4J in 64 bit windows

Tags: java, 64-bit, ocr

I want to work with Tess4J in 64 bit windows.
I have the following error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302' 
I can't change the JVM, I have to use the 64 bit
Can you give me some help? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install a 32 bit Java virtual machine and run Tess4J on it. You can have both 64 and 32 bit JREs side by side on a 64 bit operating system.

If the "user friendly installer" does not yield for that idea, just copy existing installation to another folder before installing a different one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But there is no another way?There is no dll version for win 64?

Answer (score 0):

The steps I followed to make tess4j work in 64 bit windows are as follows -
1. Developed the code in 32 bit os
2. While building the project I passed jvm variable as -d32 In 32 bit os and made the distributable jar file
3. Tested the code on 64 bit os and was working like a charm

I tried passing -d32 in 64 bit os first but IT DID NOT Work

Just follow the above steps and it would definitely work

Answer (score 0):

If you must use 64-bit JVM, you'll need Tesseract and Leptonica 64-bit DLLs. Use the ones provided by [Tesseract .NET wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/tree/master/src/lib/TesseractOcr/x64) project.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using 64 bit dlls but have still got unsatisfied link error.

The solution I am using is by using 32-bit JVM instead of 64 bit JVM.

This can be achieved by writing a batch file

```
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\..\bin\java" -jar myJar.jar
```

OR

```
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\..\bin\java" myApp
```

Instead of executing the jar file execute the batch file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if this question is still valid, but my solution was this:

1. Download zip file from tess4j
2. Copy native libraries from /lib folder
3. Rename win32-x86-64 on win32-amd64

Original library probably use wrong naming convetion.